# Trying to output the page counts of a large number of PDF's to a log file

Tags: linux, bash, pdf, exiftool

I have about 1,550 .pdf files that I want to find page counts for.

I used the command `lS -Q | grep \.pdf > ../lslog.log` to output all the file names with the extension `.pdf` to be output into a .log file with double quotes around them. I then opened the lslog.log file in gedit and replaced all the `"` (double quotes) with `'` (apostrophe) so that I can use the files that contain parentheses in the final command.

When I use the command `exiftool -"*Count*"` (which outputs any exifdata of the selected file that contains the word "count") on a single file, for example, `exiftool -"*Count*" 'examplePDF(withparantheses).pdf'` I get something like, "Page Count: 512" or whatever the page count happens to be.

However, when I use it on multiple files, for example: `exiftool -"*Count*" 'examplePDF(withparantheses).pdf' 'anotherExamplePDF.pdf'` I get

```
File not found: examplePDF(withparantheses).pdf,
======== anotherExamplePDF.pdf
Page Count                      : 362
    1 image files read
    1 files could not be read
```

So basically, I'm able to read the last file, but not the first one. This pattern continues as I add more files. It's able to find the file itself and page count of the last file, but not the other files.

Do I need to input multiple files differently? I'm using a comma right now to separate files, but even without the comma I get the same result. 
Does `exiftool` take multiple files?

Comment: Did you try: -r option and giving *.pdf (while running the command at the main folder which contains all of your .pdf files under it or in its sub-folders/tree). See this link for ex: http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/examples.html (Change the OS type radio button for more) OR this link: http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know exactly why you're getting the behaviour that you're getting, but it looks like to me like everything you're doing can be collapsed into one line:

```
exiftool -"*Count*" *.pdf
```

My output from a bunch of PDFs I had around look like this

```
======== 86A103EW00.pdf
Page Count                      : 494
======== DSET3.5_Reportable_Items_Linux.pdf
Page Count                      : 70
======== DSView 4 v4.1.0.36.pdf
Page Count                      : 7
======== DSView-Release-Notes-v4.1.0.77 (1).pdf
Page Count                      : 7
======== DSView-Release-Notes-v4.1.0.77.pdf
Page Count                      : 7
```

Comment: A word of caution: This will capture anything with Count in it, not just Page Count. I encountered a file where it displayed `Doc Change Count` as well. I tried without success to figure out how to extract only the PDF:Pages:Count tag.

Comment: `exiftool -'PageCount' somefile.pdf` works fine here.